# Multiple values for a single column

Tags: database-design, sqlite

I've got a small database with 5 tables: 3 of them are resources (material, skill and tool) and the other 2 are tasks (corrective maintenance and preventive maintenance).

Every table has a primary key with a code, and the task tables has a column for every resource code. My problem is that in some tasks, there is the possibility of having many resources of one type (2 materials, 3 skills or 6 tools). What is a good way of implementing this into an SQLite database? Creating many columns is not a good idea because there is not fixed number of resources that are needed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: *What is a good way of implementing this into an SQLite database?* This is many-to-many relations between each separate task table and each separate resource table which needs in intermediate joining table for each task-resource tables pair. *3 of them are resources (material, skill and tool) and the other 2 are tasks* The description shows that material, skill and tool is the same entity of different type, so they must be stored in the same table, not in 3 separate tables, and the same about tasks. While combining into one tasks table and one resources table there needs only one joining table

Comment: The problem with that is that different resources has different attributes, so that's why I created a table for each one with different columns.

Comment: *different resources has different attributes* This is not a problem - sparse table is not an exclusive. Or/and some attributes may be stored in EAV form.

Comment: I am going to investigate a little bit, because I am new to databases. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Lots of columns that column similar or repeated things is usually a Bad Idea.

Proper Data Normalisation is your Friend.

```
select * from resource ; 
+----+--------+
| id | name   | 
+----+--------+
|  1 | res #1 | 
|  2 | res #2 |
+----+--------+

select * from task ; 
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
| 33 | task #1 | 
| 44 | task #2 | 
+----+---------+

select * from task_resource ; 
+---------+-------------+
| task_id | resource_id | 
+---------+-------------+
|      33 |           1 | 
|      44 |           1 | 
|      44 |           2 | 
+---------+-------------+
```